# timestamp transformation in R

Tags: r, timestamp

I have a timestamp data that has the following structure where the the date and time are presented in the following way:

```
timestamp
January 22,2013 20:56
January 22,2013 08:53
January 22,2013 20:59
```

What can I do to make this into a time object in R?
I was going to write a perl script to transform the data into YEAR-MONTH-TIME HH:MM:SS format and use POSIXct to import it into a date-time object, but i was wondering if there is a shortcut to do so in R.

Comment: I see no evidence of reading `?POSIXct` and following the recommended "See Also" pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `strptime`

```
strptime('January 22,2013 20:56','%b %d,%Y %H:%M')
[1] "2013-01-22 20:56:00"
```

PS: this depends of your local:

```
Sys.setlocale('LC_TIME','FRENCH')
[1] "French_France.1252"

strptime('January 22,2013 20:56','%b %d,%Y %H:%M')
[1] NA
 Sys.setlocale('LC_TIME','ENGLISH')
[1] "English_United States.1252"
 strptime('January 22,2013 20:56','%b %d,%Y %H:%M')
[1] "2013-01-22 20:56:00"
```